# Connection string function

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating an inventory system right now but I want to put the my access database in a network access storage that is encrypted, how can I access my database using connecting string function in vb.net to code the username and password, to access my database?

Comment: Access is not concerned with encrypted locations. The file must be accessible from the file system point of view. You can use [in-file encryption](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/encrypt-a-database-by-using-a-database-password-12aa0e5c-34c6-4957-af3b-b5f5cfa9a766) instead.

Comment: Oh thanks i thought it will have an issue. thank you.